# how to use dynamic parameter view in hibernate

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jsf, view

so i am using hibernate 4 with jsf 2 in my application i want to use below query as `view` in hibernate 
i want to know how to use dynamic parameter(`1`,`12`) `bshoa.budget_sub_head_of_account_ID = 1 AND bae.budget_financial_year_ID = 12`(at line 4 in below query).
`1` and `12` are the parameters coming from jsf bean.

```
SELECT SUM(bae.`actual_expenditure`), MAX(bae.`month_of_exp`), bae.`budget_formation_ID` FROM `budget_actual_expenditure` bae, budget_assigned_sub_head_of_accounts bashoa, `budget_sub_head_of_accounts` bshoa
WHERE bae.`budget_assigned_sub_head_of_account_ID` = bashoa.`budget_assigned_sub_head_of_account_ID`
AND bashoa.`budget_sub_head_of_account_ID` = bshoa.`budget_sub_head_of_account_ID`
AND bshoa.`budget_sub_head_of_account_ID` = 1 AND bae.`budget_financial_year_ID` = 12
GROUP BY bae.`budget_formation_ID`;
```

Comment: use :param1 and :param2

Comment: how would i call parametrized view in hibernate ? can you write some line of code please ?